# Displaying a value as something different in frontend

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database which contains the data related to a video game.

Hero classes are defined as INT in my DB. So in my DB I would have a column with 'class' which will equal to let's say 1.

In the frontend I want to turn this 1 into 'Warrior'.

So my question is, should I build another table where I declare 1 = Warrior or what is the right approach here, to display this 1 as Warrior in the frontend?

Comment: You may use additional table which relates the code and the name. Or you may convert column datatype to ENUM (if the codes are adjacent integers starting from 1) - but in this case return type for this column become string instead of integer in non-numeric context.

Comment: `<?php echo ($classes===1 ? 'Warrior' : '')`